# MYSQL Transaction.Rollback failed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vba, visual-studio

I've recently been implementing a request sequence in Visual Basics, and would like to rollback when some fails. I therefore did as follows:

```
Public Class DAO
    Dim connection As New MysqlConnection
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim transaction As MySqlTransaction

    Public Sub New()
        connection = New MySqlConnection(`MYDATA_FROM_DATABASE`)
        connection.Open()
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction
        command.Connection = connection
        command.Transaction = transaction
    End Sub

    Public Sub Rollback()
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Me.GetType.Name & " - Rollback")
        Try
            transaction.Rollback()
            connection.Close()
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Rollback success")
        Catch
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Rollback failed - " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Close()
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Me.GetType.Name & " - Closing")
        Try
            transaction.Commit()
            connection.Close()
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Commit success")
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Commit failed - " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

And with that I create other DAOS classes, inheriting from that one. The other classes have other methods, for example:

```
Public Class UserDAO
    Inherits DAO

    Public Function Insere(name As String) As Boolean
        Try
            command.commandText = "INSERT INTO User(Name) VALUES('" & name & "')"
            command.ExecuteNonQuery
            Return True
        Catch
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function 
End Class
```

And, for example, I want to insert 3 users, and if it gives error I undo everything:

Suppose a method in any other location of the code

```
Public Sub Insert3Users
    Dim UserDAO As New UserDAO
    If UserDAO.Insere("USER_1") And UserDAO.Insere("USER_2") And UserDAO.Insere("USER_3") Then
        UserDAO.Close()
    Else
        UserDAO.Rollback()
    End If
End Sub
```

After calling this `Insert3Users` method, I can force the rollback, calling instead `Close()` the `Rollback()` method of the DAO class, even when it succeeds.

And taking the test I do not succeed in Rollback. Can anyone tell me why?

**EDIT - Exceptions**

**Output:**

> UserDAO - Rollback
> Rollback success

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone tell me why?

Yes, the exception thrown by your code will tell you why.

What, you don't get an exception? Let's see... oh, you get them, but you throw them away:

```
Public Sub Rollback()
    Try
        transaction.Rollback()
        connection.Close()
    Catch
    EndTry
End Sub
```

Don't do that. If people are trying to help you (and exceptions are the .NET runtime's way of helping you find bugs), listen to them. Don't close your ears and go *"lalala, I can't hear you!"*. That's what an empty `Catch` blog does.

Remove those fake exception handlers from your code (everywhere, not just in this method), and you will get useful error messages.

Comment: I thought if I did not put the exception for you it would be obvious that it was not necessary. Excuse me. Edited

Comment: @HugoFagundes: Unfortunately, it's not at all obvious: There are lots (and lots) of people who *really* do this. Thanks for updating your question! I upvoted it and hope that some MySql expert can help you here.